# Prove the strong Nullstellensatz from these two conditions

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

It is an exercise.

> Let $R=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. Assuming that
>
> (1) $R$ is Noetherian, and
>
> (2) the maximal ideas of $R$ are precisely the ideals of the form
>   $$
> (x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)
> $$
>   for $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in k^n$
>
> how to prove that $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))=\operatorname{rad}(I)$?

I know the usual prove is to use the so-called **The Rabinowitsch Trick**, i.e. consider the ideal $(I,1-yf)\subset R[y]$ for some $f\in\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V}(I))$.

But this requires knowing that $R[y]$ also satisfies $(2)$, which is not given in the question.

So, is there any other ways to proof the strong Nullstellenstaz?

Comment: did you mean that $k$ is any field? otherwise, (2) is satisfied when $k$ is algebraically closed. Also the noetherian assumption is redundant.

Comment: @adrido, yes I know we can prove (1) and (2) independently. But I guess the target of the exercise is to let you prove the Nullstellensatz with only the knowledge given in (1) and (2)...

Answer (score 1):

Since the exact question is not quite clear to me, I'll prove that for an arbitrary field $k$ the condition (2) implies  that $k$ algebraically closed. Then the Nullstellensatz can be used to answer all the questions posed by the  OP.

Consider an irreducible polynomial  $f(x_1)\in k[x_1]$ and the ideal $I=\langle f(x_1),x_2,\cdots,x_n\rangle\subset R=k[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$.
Since $R/I=k[x_1]/\langle f(x_1) \rangle$ is a field, the ideal $I$ is maximal and thus by hypothesis of the form $I=\langle x_1-a_1,x_2-a_2,\cdots,x_n-a_n\rangle$.
From this we deduce by intersecting with $k[x_1]\subset R$ :$$ k[x_1]\cap I = \langle f(x_1)\rangle  =   k[x_1]\cap \langle x_1-a_1,x_2-a_2,\cdots,x_n-a_n\rangle=  \langle x_1-a_1\rangle           $$ so that $\langle f(x_1)\rangle =\langle x_1-a_1\rangle$ .
Thus any irreducible polynomial $f\in k[x_1]$ satisfies $f(x_1)=c(x_1-a_1)\;(c\in k)$ and we have proved that $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Isn't this ($k$ algebraically closed) part of the hypothesis?

Comment: Dear @user26857: yes, you are right, but the question as posed is not clear since $I(V(I))=Rad I$ is true by the Nullstellensatz if you assume $k$ is algebraically closed.  Also, the answer to the remark "But this requires knowing that $R[y]$ also satisfies $(2)$, which is not given in the question" is obvious if you know that $k$ is algebraically closed. But I'll take your comment (for which I thank you) into account by modifying  my answer in order to emphasize that what I'm proving is that (2) implies that $k$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, thanks! I have to say I might post a bad question. Indeed I am not sure the meaning of this exercise. Anyway, your answer helps a lot:)

Comment: I'm glad the answer helped you,  hxhxhx88.